# Despite error cannot read property length of null, the code works

Tags: angular, angular-material2

This looks pretty good to me.

```
<mat-form-field class="example-medium-width">
  <textarea matInput name="description" [(ngModel)]="description" placeholder="Description" maxlength="50"  #field_description="ngModel">
  </textarea>
  <mat-hint align="end">
     {{field_description.value.length}} / 50 Chars please.
   </mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

But for some reason, browser is not happy!

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
>       at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (CreateLearningPlanComponent.html:75)

However, as I type characters into the text-area element, I can see the value ( the current number of chars in the text-area that is) is correctly being reported! So I see 1/50 ... 2/50. and this tell me that  and stopping the user input eventually at the 50th char. So the `field_description.value.length` seems to be OK.

But then the length of undefined!

But why do I get this error on the console.log you think?

Comment: {{field_description.value?.length}} should take care of the error. field_description.value is indefined at the start, thus the length of the null error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use safe navigation operator,

```
<mat-hint align="end">
     {{field_description?.value?.length}} / 50 Chars please.
</mat-hint>
```

Answer (score 1):

How are you defining the `description` field in your component class?

If you are not setting a default value, it is undefined when the form first appears so you see that error.

As soon as you start to type, it is no longer undefined and it works as you expected.

So you can either set a default value (such as an empty string) or you can use the safe navigation operator as others here have suggested.